# Security alert in google play console using an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-security

Kindly help me how to fix below issue. Thanks in advance.

Your app is using an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Vulnerable classes:

lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.d$1

lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.e$1

Please fix the issue before: 12/21/2020

Comment: I never use HostNameVerifier in my application google still sending mail and fix the deadline and I need a suggestion for this question.

Comment: I never use Paypal in my application but I am using Braintree which is internally using paypal therefore please help me out.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the Braintree SDK. If you are, and you still get this report, talk to Braintree.

Comment: Earlier I was using com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+ and now I have upgraded to com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1. Thankyou

Comment: @ShobhitGupta Hi ! I had the same problem 3 monts ago. I upgraded the braintree / paypal library and the alert disappeared. This morning, my app was removed from the store for the same reason. I don't understand. No time limit. What about your app ?